# Symfony: using $this->widgetSchema->setFormFormatterName('list')

Tags: symfony1

im using $this->widgetSchema->setFormFormatterName('list'); this way
below to render my form as a list but it is still a table. Any idea?

```
public function configure()
  {

            parent::configure();

            $this->widgetSchema->setFormFormatterName('list');

  }

}
```

Any idea?

Javi

Comment: Have you cleared your cache? :-)

Comment: Hi richsage, 

yes i cleared the cache, anyway now i have realized the the _form.php file has table tags, so.. if the _form.php is created when i create the module, how is possible the line $this->widgetSchema->setFormFormatterName(‘list’) can change the _form.php file!? or what happens exactly?

Comment: Sounds like you're using admin generator, which creates the form partial automatically.

Comment: Did it uses embedded form ? the setFormFormatterName method applies only to current form.

You should remove _form.php from templates to see generated list

Comment: @richsage: the filter form is at the frontend. I created my module using doctrine:genereate-module. Thanks.
@Benoit: i removed the content of _form.php and wrote <?php echo $form?> and i got the form as a list. What should i do to apply a formatter to all the forms?. Thanks.

Comment: Aneyway if i write $this->widgetSchema->setFormFormatterName(‘table’); it doesn't show the form as a table...

Answer (score 1):

to apply a formatter to all the forms use the following line in the setup() of your config\ProjectConfiguration.class.php

```
class ProjectConfiguration extends sfProjectConfiguration
{
  public function setup()
  {
    sfWidgetFormSchema::setDefaultFormFormatterName('list');
  }

}
```